# Android NDK : No Rule to make target CCConfiguration.cpp needed by CCConfiguration.o

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

NDK build fails with following log,

```
Android NDK: WARNING:F:\FlappyMathSaga\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\cocos2d-x-2.2.2/cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: hellocpp_shared <= main.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: hellocpp_shared <= AppDelegate.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: hellocpp_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: hellocpp_shared <= CCParallaxNodeExtras.cpp
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/f/FlappyMathSaga/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/AstroSpaceWar/../../../../cocos2dx/CCConfiguration.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dx_static/CCConfiguration.o'.  Stop.
```

Platform Details 
    Android-NDK: android-ndk-r9c
    Cocos: cocos2d-x

Androidk.mk File

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := hellocpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libhellocpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/CCParallaxNodeExtras.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx)
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android)
```

I tried  following suggestions from cocos/stackoverflow

i. Deleting Libs and Objs

ii. Checking NDKMODULEPATH for spaces

Also, CDT build completes with following warning

```
Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/f/FlappyMathSaga/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/AstroSpaceWar/../../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: I have encountered similar issues many times and a simple clean and build should work without any issues.

Comment: I already tried it, Whenever I delete Obj and Libs , I do clean build